# Qt process getting automatically killed

Tags: qt

On a button click, two processes (*p* and *pr*) need to be launched. But unfortunately my second process (pr) automatically gets killed. Function *OutLan* never gets called.

```
QString lancn;
void MainWindow::on_lineEditPathSet(QString inputpath)
{ 

    QString parameters = " " + settings.value("save_nmix").toString() + " " + settings.value("save_norm_method").toString() + " " + settings.value("save_thresh_value").toString() + " " + settings.value("save_oos_thresh").toString() + " " + flag;
    QString cmd = "test.exe " + inputpath + parameters;

    if (p)
    {
      p->setEnvironment( QProcess::systemEnvironment() );
      p->setProcessChannelMode( QProcess::SeparateChannels );
      p->start(cmd);
      p->waitForStarted();
      connect( p, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(OutTable()) );
      connect( p, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(ErrConsole()));
    }

    QMessageBox msgBox(this);
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Launching Testing Process");
    msgBox.setText("Testing process is being initialized.\n\nIt may take some time.\n\nPlease wait.");
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    msgBox.exec();
    if(lang_method.compare("ConvoNet")==0)
    {
        QProcess pr;

        QStringList params;
        params.append("test.py");
        params.append(inputpath);
        pr.start("python", params);
        pr.waitForStarted();
        connect( &pr, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(OutLan()) );

    }
}

    void MainWindow::OutLan()
    {
        QProcess *p = dynamic_cast<QProcess *>( sender() );
        lancn=p->readLine();
    }
```

Output:

QProcess: Destroyed while process ("python") is still running.

Please tell me why the process (*pr*) is getting killed?

Comment: Your `QProcess` is a local variable and will be destructed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @G.M.  Thanks. It worked. Just one more question : When the program test.py is called on folder containing multiple files, OutLan function is called only once ,that is, only for the first file. Can you tell me the reason ?

Comment: Can't really say without seeing the complete code (including that for `test.py`).  As a first guess, however, I suspect either `test.py` is buffering output *or* your `OutLan` implementation is failing to read *all* available input.  Try `while (p->canReadLine()){ lancn = p->readLine(); }` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @G.M. You were spot on. It worked. Thank you very much for all the help.